# Cant see image from project directory

Tags: python, django

I tried to handle this but I gave up. I have folder with images and I want to display my some image in html view but It wont work.

I followed this tutorial [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

this my project tree:

[image]

As you can see I tried to create plenty of directories to make it work.

This is my settins:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# STATICFILES_DIRS = [
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media"),
#     '/webstore/',
# ]

MEDIA_ROOT = '/webstore/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

this is my html view where I try to display my image

```
<img src="/media/example.jpg" />
```

this is my `urls.py` file

```
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from djangoproject import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('webstore.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2):

`MEDIA_URL` is the base URL to serve the media files uploaded by users, and `MEDIA_ROOT` is the local path where they reside.

so try to use it on your `setting.py`

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

and on your main `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
]

if settings.DEBUG: urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and should the entire image will be saved in your `djangoproject/media/`

one more thing don't forget to add `{% load staticfiles %}` on top your `html` file. `{% load staticfiles %}` tells Django to load the staticfiles template tags that are provided by the `django.contrib.staticfiles` application.

Answer (score 1):

`MEDIA_ROOT` is the absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.

`STATIC_ROOT` is the absolute filesystem path to the directory from which you’d like to serve these files.

Since, you would like to serve images, give the absolute path of your static directory to STATIC_ROOT.
Give relative path with respect to your STATIC_ROOT in STATIC_URL.
Also, change your `urls.py` with the static_url and static_root.

Another Suggestion: Easier way to display an image is to upload it to image servers like imgur and give the url of the image in the html.
For e.g. :

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbegK.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to do is

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/absolutepath/to/djangoproject/webstore/media/'
```

Then you have already

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and try

```
<img src="/media/example.jpg" />
```